# Why can't I set a variable to ConnectionServiceName for task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3

Tags: azure-pipelines

Originally, I had the following code for the AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3 task with the ConnectedServiceName and subscriptionId hard coded.

```
            - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
              displayName: 'ARM Template deployment: Resource Group scope'
              inputs:
                ConnectedServiceName: 'Actual Connection Service Name'
                subscriptionId: 'Actual Subscription Id'
                etc.
```

The above worked fine.

I wanted to make the processing more "templated", so I added these variables.

```
      variables: 
        connectedServiceName: 'Actual Connection Service Name'
        subscriptionId: 'Actual Subscription Id'
```

And updated the task with:

```
            - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
              displayName: 'ARM Template deployment: Resource Group scope'
              inputs:
                ConnectedServiceName: '$(connectedServiceName)'
                subscriptionId: '$(subscriptionId)'
```

The subscriptionId works, but the ConnectedServiceName gives me the following error.

There was a resource authorization issue: "The pipeline is not valid. Job Deploy: Step input ConnectedServiceName references service connection $(connectedServiceName) which could not be found. The service connection does not exist or has not been authorized for use. For authorization details, refer to [https://aka.ms/yamlauthz."](https://aka.ms/yamlauthz.%22)

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

The area I am having issues with:

```
  - stage: SysTest
    displayName: Deploy to SysTest
    dependsOn: Build
    jobs:
    - deployment: Deploy
      pool:
        vmImage: windows-latest
      environment: SysTest
      variables: 
        environment: systest
        subscriptionId: subId
        connectedServiceName: 'test' 
        skuName: B1
        location: 'East US'
        owner: RAC
        appName: PocYamlDeploymentApi
        resourceGroupName: $(appName)-rg-$(environment)
        appServiceName: gbli-$(appName)-svc-$(environment)
        appInsightsName: $(appName)-ins-$(environment)
        appServicePlanName: $(appName)-asp-$(environment)
        siteName: gbli-$(appName)-svc-$(environment)
          
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:               
            - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
              displayName: 'Download pipeline artifacts'
              inputs:
                buildType: current
                artifact: drop
                
            - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
              displayName: 'ARM Template deployment: Resource Group scope'
              inputs:
                ConnectedServiceName: '$(connectedServiceName)'
                subscriptionId: '$(subscriptionId)'
                resourceGroupName: '$(resourceGroupName)'
                location: '$(location)'
                csmFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/AzureDeploy/azureDeploy.json'
```

My Solution (After Converting to a Template)
Note: There is still more I want clean up below.

1. In my Main yaml, added variables for SysTest and QA (will need 2 more for UAT and Prod)

Note: I don't understand why this for root level variables and not stage or job level variables but it does not.  (Maybe I will try again later).
My guess is the root level variables are "transformed" differently then stage or job level variables. Maybe during compile time vs runtime?

```
variables: 
 - name: connectedServiceNameSysTest
   value: 'Azure Systest - Service Connection'
 - name: connectedServiceNameQa
   value: 'Azure QA  - Service Connection'
```

2. In my Main yaml, call the template.yaml

```
  - stage: DeployToSysTest
    displayName: Deploy to SysTest
    dependsOn: Build
    jobs:
      - template: templates/job-deployment.yml
        parameters:
          environment: SysTest
          connectedServiceName: '$(connectedServiceNameSysTest)'
          subscriptionId: 5546f831-a071-4d28-b9ee-1ad0d4fdfd60
```

3. In template.yaml, set up parameters

```
parameters:
- name: environment
  type: string
- name: connectedServiceName
  type: string
- name: subscriptionId
  type: string
```

4. In template.yaml, use parameters

```
       - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
          displayName: 'ARM Template deployment: Resource Group scope'
          inputs:
            ConnectedServiceName: ${{ parameters.connectedServiceName }} 
            subscriptionId:  ${{ parameters.subscriptionId }} 
            resourceGroupName: '$(resourceGroupName)'
            location: '$(location)'
            csmFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/AzureDeploy/azureDeploy.json'
```

If anyone has a better way please share.

Comment: Include the entire template. Variable scoping can be tricky and without seeing the entire template and how the templates are consumed and referenced between one another, it's hard to provide an answer. Most likely, you've defined your variable at a scope that is inaccessible within your template.

Comment: @DanielMann Thank you for the response. I am not using a template. All the code is in 1 file. However, I do want to more the code to a template but first I wanted to identify all of the fields that should be parameters.  Per your request, I added the block of code I am having issues with.

Comment: Want to add I tried the following.  1. Moved the variable  connectedServiceName to the stage level and got the same result.  2. Moved the variable  connectedServiceName to the root level and and it worked. But, not what I am looking for since the variable needs to be unique per stage.

Comment: I found a solution. I don't love it but it works.  Please share if you have a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the error message, the variable $(connectedServiceName) is **not** correctly defined in your yaml.

I can reproduce the same error:
[image]

1. If you define the variable and task in **same yaml**, please check the [variable scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#variable-scopes) below. Make sure the variable is defined in correct scope.

[image]

For example:

```
variables:
- name: ServiceConnectionName
  value: ARMConn1
- name: subscriptionId
  value: 265xx-6xx2-4dxx-axxx-40xxa038a

jobs:
- job: Deploy
  steps:
  - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
    inputs:
      deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
      connectedServiceName: '$(ServiceConnectionName)'
      subscriptionId: '$(subscriptionId)'
      ...
```

2. If you define variable in main yaml, but task in [template yaml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops&pivots=templates-includes), which means they are in **different yaml**, you need to use `parameter` instead.

Main yaml:

```
variables:
- name: ServiceConnectionName
  value: ARMConn1
- name: subscriptionId
  value: 265xx-6xx2-4dxx-axxx-40xxa038a

jobs:
- job: Deploy
  steps:
    - template: template.yml
      parameters:
        ServiceConnectionName: $(ServiceConnectionName)
        subscriptionId: $(subscriptionId)
```

template.yml:

```
parameters:
- name: 'ServiceConnectionName'
  type: string
- name: 'subscriptionId'
  type: string

steps:
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  inputs:
    deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
    connectedServiceName: '${{ parameters.ServiceConnectionName}}'
    subscriptionId: '${{ parameters.subscriptionId}}'
    ....
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. As I mentioned above, I added the code I am having issues with at the bottom of the post. I am working with one file. I tried the following: 1.  Moved the variable from the job level to the stage level, same error. 2. Moved the variable to the root level, this worked. But not really what I want since the variable really is a stage level variable.  Do you have any additional thoughts?

Comment: I found a solution. I don't love it but it works.  Please share if you have a better way.  Your explanation of how variables are scoped gave me the idea to try and set the variable at the root level. So, thank you.

Comment: I can reproduce the same error with your original yaml. The variable value is correctly set actually, you can validate with a `- script: echo $(connectedServiceName)` task for checking. The issue is caused by the task `AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3`, you can use Template expression `${{ variables.connectedServiceName }}` if variable is defined in deployment job, it works.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a shot tomorrow.

Comment: I was able to get this to work,  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to know it works! Happy new year!

Comment: Happy New Year to you as well.